# What is the reason behind integer() == integer() not equal TRUE

Tags: r

Why in the following example the last condition returns logical(0) instead of TRUE?
What is the reason behind it?

```
> integer(2) == integer(2)
[1] TRUE TRUE
> integer(1) == integer(1)
[1] TRUE
> integer(0) == integer(0)
logical(0)
```

And similarly

```
> NULL == NULL
logical(0)

> a <- NULL
> b <- NULL
> a == b
logical(0)
```

Comment: You're looking for `as.integer(.)`. `integer(0)` is an integer vector of length=0, not 0 of type integer.

Comment: Well, yes. This is obvious. But I still do not understand why it is this way. I would like to learn the idea behind it. It is confusing for me.

Comment: Because something of zero length, having zero content, can't be equal or unequal to anything.

Comment: @Arun - clearly those should be upgraded to numeric(0) since 1 is numeric :D

Comment: `logical(0)` does not say it's not true. It also doesn't say it's not false.  R knows the result is logical.  But based on input, it doesn't know if it's true or false.

Comment: Thank you all for ideas. I think that answer of Richard was helpful.

Comment: `==` return a logical vector of the same length as its inputs. Here, the length of `integer(0)` is zero so it returns a logical vector of length zero (`logical(0)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the objects you are unsuccessfully trying to compare are not numerical entities, but data representation objects.

If you try `identical(integer(0), integer(0))` you can see the objects are the same, it is just that they are not comparable.

Comment: Thanks you Oscar, interesting.

Comment: Also take into account that the special objects `NA`, `NaN` and `NULL` have different representations (storage modes and classes), which can influence your comparisons depending on how those where generated. Try: `class(as.integer(NA))`, `class(as.numeric(NA))` and  `identical(as.integer(NA), as.numeric(NA))`.